# Custom python function is not running

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
names=["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"]
itMarks=[90,98,87,98,78]

def printMainMenu():
    print(" Main Menu")
    print(" =========")

    print(" (1)Add Student")
    print(" (2)Search Student")
    print(" (3)Delete Student")
    print(" (4)List Student")
    print(" (5)Exit")

    choice = int(input("Enter Your choice[1-5]:"))
    return choice

def searchStudent(names,itMarks):
    name = input("Enter Name")
    i = names.index(names)
    print("Index is" + i)


def deleteStudent(student,itMarks):
    name = input("Enter Name to remove")
    student.remove(names)
    print("Successfully Deleted" + names)

def removeStudent(names):
    name = input("Enter name to remove")
    name.remove(name)
    print("Successfully deleted" + names)


def addStudent(names, itMarkas):
    name = input("Enter Name")
    names.append(names)
    itMarks = input("Enter IT Marks")
    itMarks.append(itMarks)

def listStudent(names, itMarks):
    for i in range(0, len(names)):
        print(names[1], "", itMarks[i])

names = []
itMarks = []

choice = 1
while choice >= 1 and choice <= 4:
    choice = printMainMenu()

    if choice == 1:
        addStudent(names, itMarks)

    elif choice == 2:
        searchStudent(names, itMarks)

    elif choice == 3:
        deleteStudent(names, itMarks)

    elif choice == 4:
        listStudent(names, itMarks)

    elif choice == 5:
        print("Exit from the program")
    else:
        print("invalid choice!")
        choice = 1
```

I am new to the programming in Python. The following Python code is written to do some tasks with the array. There are two array named names and itMarks. And there are some functions :

```
addStudent() - To add students to the array
searchStudent() - To search a student with in the list.
deleteStudent() - To delete the given student from the list.
listStudent() - To list out the all the names of the students in the list.
```

When the program runs, it asks to select a choice. Then it do the task according to their choice. But when I run this coding it shows the errors.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
ERROR :
```

When I select the choice 1 (Add student) and input name after the error is yield.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BAALANPC\Desktop\new 3.py", line 59, in <module>
    addStudent(names, itMarks)
  File "C:\Users\BAALANPC\Desktop\new 3.py", line 42, in addStudent
    name = input("Enter Name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rtrt' is not defined
```

Comment: you should try decompose the code into individual blocks that you can test with an expected input / output. Generally questions of "why does this not work" will get heavily down voted. Once you have done that you can ask a  more refined question

Comment: What are the errors, please post them also.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question title

Comment: Maybe a typecast problem. Try to compare with `choice == "1"` and so on.

Comment: @MaxM He converts to `int` here: `choice = int(input("Enter Your choice[1-5]:"))`

Comment: Where is `rtrt` in your code?

Comment: What is meant by 'rtrt'?

Comment: The error you got is `NameError: name 'rtrt' is not defined`. It seems like you are using some `rtrt` which is not defined.

Comment: The traceback is saying the user tried to input `rtrt`. This will happen if you forget to put *quotations* around your inputs.

Comment: oh! `rtrt` is just a sample name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their so many mistakes in naming

In **addStudent**

```
def addStudent(names, itMarkas):
    name = input("Enter Name")
    names.append(name)          # names cant appent it should be name
    itMark = input("Enter IT Marks")   # here itmark not itMarks
    itMarks.append(itMark)
```

In  **searchStudent**

```
 def searchStudent(names,itMarks):
     name = input("Enter Name")
     i = names.index(name)   # try to find index of name not names
     print("Index is" + i)
```

In **deleteStudent**

```
def deleteStudent(student,itMarks):
    name = input("Enter Name to remove")
    student.remove(name)        # try to remove name not names
    print("Successfully Deleted" + name)
```

after change above I run its running you have to also change the naming of the variable  for all methods

**Output**

```
 Main Menu
 =========
 (1)Add Student
 (2)Search Student
 (3)Delete Student
 (4)List Student
 (5)Exit
 Enter Your choice[1-5]:1
 add student
 Enter Name"aaa" 
 Enter IT Marks111
 Main Menu
 =========
(1)Add Student
(2)Search Student
(3)Delete Student
(4)List Student
(5)Exit
Enter Your choice[1-5]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the correct form:

```
def searchStudent(names,itMarks):
    name = input("Enter Name")
    i = names.index(name)
    print("Index is" + i)
```

note that I changed names to name.
also the same mistake again

```
def deleteStudent(student,itMarks):
    name = input("Enter Name to remove")
    student.remove(name)
    print("Successfully Deleted" + names)
```

Comment: I can't tell which one is the line 52 and which is line 35, post the error

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr revise your code

**searchStudent()**: You shouldn't need the `itMarks` argument if you're not using it inside your function at all. `names` refers to the list of names, but you are really trying to search `name`. `i` is an integer that is attempting to be concatenated with a string. Not allowed. It should be `str(i)`.

**deleteStudent()**: Better to keep your arguments consistent and use `names` rather than `student`. Again, same problem as above, should be `.remove(name)` and you shouldn't need the `itMarks` argument. `print` statement should refer to `name` not `names`.

**removeStudent()**: This is the same code as *deleteStudent()*, but not used, so not sure why it's there.

**addStudent()**: Typo in the argument, `.append(name)`. You have a global variable and a local variable named the same thing, which are conflicting to the program. Change the `input` set to `itMark` and `.append(itMark)`.

**listStudent()**: `print` statement has a typo, `1` should be `i`. Not sure why the empty string is included as well.

Underneath your function `def`'s, you restate your variables as empty lists. This can lead to `ValueError`s from a lot of your functions as you're trying to look something up or modify something in an empty list. Simply delete this code.

Additionally, any error will `break` your `while` loop. I suggest adding more booleans or using a `try except` clause to catch these errors.

Good luck!